# Set synchronous timeout for client from JaxWsProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-ws

I have an issue in my (spring boot) API where occasionally a SOAP service it calls will take over a minute to respond, resulting in a SocketTimeoutException. After a lot of searching I've narrowed the cause down to this bit of code:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T createWsService(Class<T> serviceClass, String url) {
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setServiceClass(serviceClass);
        factory.setAddress(url);

        LoggingInInterceptor loggingInInterceptor = new LoggingInInterceptor();
        loggingInInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
        factory.getInInterceptors().add(loggingInInterceptor);

        LoggingOutInterceptor loggingOutInterceptor = new LoggingOutInterceptor();
        loggingOutInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
        factory.getOutInterceptors().add(loggingOutInterceptor);

        return (T) factory.create();
    }
```

When debugging through I can see the `factory.create()` returns a proxy object but this is cast to the interface from the ws supplier. The proxy object contains a [ClientImpl](https://www.javatips.net/api/cxf-master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/endpoint/ClientImpl.java) which I can see has a default synchronous timeout of 60000 (a minute).

I tried adding the following:

```
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("cxf.synchronous.timeout", 1);
        factory.setProperties(properties);
```

to set the property (using 1 as a test to check it works) but this just sets the property as an endpoint of the container object. There are no methods on the interface I need to use that let me set any properties.

I also tried casting the returned object to JaxWsClientProxy to set it myself but this didn't work despite it showing with that structure when debugging.

How can I increase the timeout here? I'm open to abandoning the JaxWsProxyFactoryBean approach in favour of something more flexible if that's what it takes but I'd prefer to keep changes to a minimum if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I've found it, the property I needed is `"javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout"` instead of `"cxf.synchronous.timeout"`